# Why does 0 < undefined return false instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

Why does `0 < undefined` return `false` instead of undefined?

Based on the abstract relational comparison part of the ES6 spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison I think it should return undefined. (please click the spec to understand what I'm saying)

I don't entirely understand the ReturnIfAbrupt part, but it doesn't seem like that should stop the comparison. Then I interpreted 3 and 4 as basically saying since its using a < flag and not a > flag then keep on going. It should ignore 5 because 0 and undefined are both not strings.

So then on 6. it says to convert 0 to a number, which is 0 and to convert undefined to a number which should be NaN as per http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber

Since 6f states "If ny is NaN, return undefined" then why am I getting false rather than undefined? It's the same result in Chrome, Safari and Firefox so I'm assuming all 3 browsers aren't interpreting the spec wrong.

Comment: FWIW `0 < NaN === false` and `0 > NaN === false`. My guess is the `<` and `>` operator returns a boolean result which is either `true` or `false` and `undefined` is not only NOT a value (it is a variable) but is also not in the set of booleans

Comment: BTW, the latest spec is [*ECMAScript 2016*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html), which is ed 7. In the middle of this year ECMAScript ed 8 aka 2017 will be released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you are looking at the specification of the Abstract Relational Comparison operation but not the `<` operator.

The specification of the `<` operator falls under Relational Operators in ES6: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Paraphrasing the spec, the `<` operator works as follows:

- Perform an Abstract Relational Comparison
- If it returns undefined then return false otherwise return whatever it returns

So there is a hardcoded part of the spec that converts the `undefined` return value from the Abstract Relational Comparison operation to `false`

---

Note: It's specified the same way in ES7: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation so it's not going to change. Also, it was specified that way in ES5 as well.

Comment: It has been that way since the very beginning in [*ECMAScript ed 1 §11.8.1*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf). ;-)